# change openlayers3 zoom sensitivity

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm currently using OL3 with tiled map (ol.layer.Tile) with 4 zoom levels of tiles. I want the zoom to be more sensitive and allow 8 zoom levels instead of 4, each 2 for each tile level. any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html), you can manage zoom setting with several properties in your View object:

> - **maxResolution**: The maximum resolution used to determine the resolution constraint. It is used together with minResolution (or
>     maxZoom) and zoomFactor. If unspecified it is calculated in such a way
>     that the projection's validity extent fits in a 256x256 px tile. If
>     the projection is Spherical Mercator (the default) then maxResolution
>     defaults to 40075016.68557849 / 256 = 156543.03392804097.
> - **minResolution**: The minimum resolution used to determine the resolution constraint. It is used together with maxResolution (or
>     minZoom) and zoomFactor. If unspecified it is calculated assuming 29
>     zoom levels (with a factor of 2). If the projection is Spherical
>     Mercator (the default) then minResolution defaults to
>     40075016.68557849 / 256 / Math.pow(2, 28) = 0.0005831682455839253.
> - **maxZoom**: The maximum zoom level used to determine the resolution constraint. It is used together with minZoom (or
>     maxResolution) and zoomFactor. Default is 28. Note that if
>     minResolution is also provided, it is given precedence over maxZoom.
> - **minZoom**: The minimum zoom level used to determine the resolution constraint. It is used together with maxZoom (or minResolution) and
>     zoomFactor. Default is 0. Note that if maxResolution is also provided,
>     it is given precedence over minZoom.
> - **zoomFactor**: The zoom factor used to determine the resolution constraint. Default is 2.

Example to get 2 view zoom levels for each tile grid zoom level of your XYZ sourece:

```
var source = new ol.source.XYZ({
  // your source configuration here
});
var resolutions = source.getTileGrid().getResolutions();
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: source
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0,
    maxResolution: resolutions[0],
    minResolution: resolutions[resolutions.length-1],
    zoomFactor: 1.5
  })
});
```

Comment: I'm using ol.source.xyz

Comment: using ol.source.xyz you still have a ol.View object to set up. I believe that modifying that object you can change your map zoom level.

Comment: @tfidelis is right. I edited the example in the answer to better address the question.

Comment: @amitdar please accept the answer if it solved your problem.